# Powershell is outputting a batch file that won't run

Tags: powershell, batch-file, export

I've written a Powershell script that allows the user to select something from a list. This is then combined with code for a batch file which is then output.
This all works perfectly, the code that is in the batch file is correct, it saves correctly as a batch file but when I go to run it by double clicking on the batch file it flashes a box up on screen for a second then disappears without running what it was supposed to do.

Yet if I copy and paste that same text into notepad, save as the exact same thing and double click it, it executes correctly. How do I fix this?

Tried copy and pasting the contents of the batch file into notepad and saving as test.bat - which then works fine.

```
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
$x = $listBox.SelectedItem
$out = "@echo off ........."
$out | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\test.bat
}
```

Instead of the batch file executing it simply flashes a box on screen for an instant.

What should happen is the batch file executes the code in its script.
The batch file has both a pause and a timeout, it also fails to do the task it is supposed to do.

Comment: @Compo I forgot to mention the batch file contains both a timeout and a pause. It also does not do the task it is supposed to do.

Comment: Did you forget to mention how you're running the batch file too! or are you really expecting that piping the content of the `$out` variable to a file with a `.bat` extension is the same as running the file?

Comment: the `Out-File` cmdlet defaults to unicode encoding. you likely want to use `-Encoding ASCII` instead.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That worked, thankyou!

Comment: @Crasos - you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

`Out-File` (and `>`) creates "Unicode" files by default in Windows PowerShell<sup>[1]</sup>, i.e., [UTF-16LE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)-encoded files, which `cmd.exe`, the shell that processes batch files, doesn't understand.

`cmd.exe` expects *OEM*-encoded files, i.e., the OEM code page associated with the active (legacy) system locale. (OEM code pages are 8-bit supersets of the 7-bit ASCII encoding).

Therefore, you should use `-Encoding Oem` to create your batch file:

```
$out = "@echo off ........."
$out | Out-File -Encoding Oem -LiteralPath C:\temp\test.bat
```

Since you're outputting *strings*, you could also use `Set-Content`, which is slightly more efficient.

---

<sup>[1] In the cross-platform PowerShell *Core* edition, the more sensible default is UTF-8 (without BOM).</sup>